# Any way to set project property from code?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

In MVC, if you navigate to the `Properties` of the project and go to the `Web` tab, you can set a specific page. I was wondering if there is any way to do this from the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think so. That page is for VS to know what page should launch when you press F5. If you just want to set the default page for the application (when no page is called) just set the desired action and controller in the default route.

Maybe you have a specific purpose to want that?

Answer (score 0):

In MVC, there was no relation with physical file in webserver and the URL in browser. *(It use routing system with URL mapping rules, which map incoming URLs and route to the right Controller and Action method.)*
So you cannot set specific page as "Startup Page" like in normal WebForm. Even if you can do in VS, this will open with file extension (*.aspx, *.cshtml) in browser. You need to create your own default route.